# POSTGRES Update rows on same table with join query

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have tables `account` and `account_devices`

**account** table

```
id | account_id | state
1  | USD-001    | normal
2  | USD-002    | late
3  | USD-003    | default
4  | USD-004    | inactive
5  | USD-005    | inactive
```

**account_devices** table

```
id | account_id | start_date | end_date
1  | USD-001    | 2021-01-02 | 
2  | USD-002    | 2021-02-03 | 
3  | USD-003    | 2021-03-04 |
4  | USD-004    | 2021-04-05 |
5  | USD-005    | 2021-05-06 | 2022-01-01
```

Now I would like to set `end_date` of just `inactive` state accounts if that are not set (null)

I have tried with this update query:

```
update account_devices ad
set end_date = ad.start_date
from account_devices
join account on account.account_id = account_devices.account_id
where account_devices.end_date is null and account.state = 'inactive';
```

The problem with the above mention update query is to set `end_date` of all records whether its account state is `inactive` or not.

Here is the final result after the update query:

(It's not what I am expecting - problematic)

```
id | account_id | start_date | end_date
1  | USD-001    | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-02
2  | USD-002    | 2021-02-03 | 2021-02-03
3  | USD-003    | 2021-03-04 | 2021-03-04
4  | USD-004    | 2021-04-05 | 2021-04-05
5  | USD-005    | 2021-05-06 | 2022-01-01
```

But actually I required something like that:

```
id | account_id | start_date | end_date
1  | USD-001    | 2021-01-02 |
2  | USD-002    | 2021-02-03 |
3  | USD-003    | 2021-03-04 |
4  | USD-004    | 2021-04-05 | 2021-04-05
5  | USD-005    | 2021-05-06 | 2022-01-01
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your attention. I'm looking forward to your reply.

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.6)  "*Do not repeat the target table as a from_item unless you intend a self-join*"